# How to point/direct domain name to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, dns, domain-name

I want to point a domain name newdomainname.com from a domain service provider (Hostinger) to a subfolder and/or subdomain on my existing website eg.

```
existingwebsite.com/subfolder
```

so when I access newdomainname.com it will direct to that subfolder while showing newdomainname.com on the address bar. How can I achieve this?

Also if it can be done with subdomain I would also like to know how. eg: pointing newdomainname.com to:

```
subdomain.existingwebsite.com
```